# Observable from callback, where callback is not error-first

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5, rxjs6

Say I have this:

```
const register = function(cb){

   process.on('message', m => {

         cb(m, (err, v) => {

            process.send({error: err, value: v});

         });
   });

};
```

we use the above like:

```
register((m, cb) => {

   // do something with m

   setTimeout(() => {
      cb('some error', m);
   }, 100);

});
```

my question is - is there a way to use `Rx.Observable` with this - most examples of `Rx.Observable.fromCallback` will wrap an *error-first* callback. But in this case, the callback is not error first. As an exercise, how to make it work for non-error first callbacks? Here is a start:

```
const {Observable, bindNodeCallback} = require('rxjs');

const obs = bindNodeCallback(register);

const subscription = obs().subscribe(v => {

}, e => {
       // this gets hit since the first arg is not an error
 });
```

anyone dealt with this one before?

**Update**, I got a little closer, the following example uses setInterval instead of process.on('message') so it is easier to work with for testing:

https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/ea5d754d6ca6c92ca7e3bddc7eb318c2

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to create an Observable which emits any time a `'message'` event is received by `process`.

If this is the case, I think that `bindCallback` is not the right approach. The Observable returned invoking the function created with `bindCallback` emits only once and it emits the data which are the parameters used to invoke the call.

What you want is a Observable that emits many times, each time a message is received (again if my understanding is right).

To accomplish this you may use `create` static method of Observable. The code could look something similar to the following

```
Observable<any>(
        (subscriber: Observer<any>) => {
            process.on('message', 
                m => {
                    // do stuff with m
                }
            );
        }
);
```

You may find a bit of reasoning around `bindCallback` in [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c#fb7e).